# Provide a clear logic to reverse numbers in spreadsheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet, user-interface, usability

This may be tricky to explain but I will do my best.

I have a load of numbers, and I need to reverse some of them. Only a human can decide which number does or doesn't need reversing. So a column with manual input needs to be involved. I have three ways to do it, but I'm not happy with any of them, ***is there a better way to do this?***

---

## Option 1 - type the factor in manually

[image]

- No need for extra columns
- I can easily use Conditional Formatting or perform boolean operations directly.
- **But** I cannot type quickly. I have to type two characters in each row which is slow. Or I have to type two chars in some rows and one char in others - even slower.

---

## Option 2 - type a 1 or 0, use helper column with IF to provide a +1/-1 factor

[image]

The manual input is ones or zeroes, and then column C provides a factor.

- I only need to quickly type one character.
- I can easily use Conditional Formatting or perform boolean operations directly.
- **But** I am not comfortable with how to define the meaning of ones and zeroes, I feel a mental conflict:

  - a factor of +1 means ***not*** reversing the number, therefore ***not*** performing an operation. This would mean if I don't want to reverse the number, I need to type a 0. As a result, I would need to type 1 to produce a factor -1. This is nonsense.
  - ok, so let's define the logic of this column so that 1 results in +1 and 0 results in -1. So how do I give this column a meaningful header? *"Keep original sign?"* - I don't like that as a way of asking if the reversing operation should be performed. In this option, I have to use human language to effectively say that yes means negative. The other options avoid it.

---

## Option 3 - type + or -, use helper column with IF to provide a +1/-1 factor

[image]

- I can type quickly and don't need to worry about wording the column header.
- **But** my input is text, and I cannot easily use Conditional Formatting or perform boolean operations directly.

Comment: You could use VBA to create Buttons in column 'B'.  And then a single mouse click could toggle the cell between `1` and `-1`, with the button displaying `+` or `-`.  And a formula in column three to compute the appropriate value.

Answer (score 0):

If a human will have to decide where to "reverse" there is no other way than having someone enter the decision in some way... Either of the last two might then be the preferred choice.

To do the actual "reversal" you might use something similar to any of these...

`=-A1`                                      will swap the sign of any non-zero number.
`=NOT(A2)`                               swaps TRUE/FALSE,
`=NOT(A3)*1`                           swaps 1/0

and...

`=IF(A4="YES","NO","YES")`
turns an explicit "YES" into a "NO" (anything else turns into a YES, case sensitive)

For an explicit YES/NO
`=IF(A4="YES","NO",IF(A4="YES","NO","Unknown entity")`

Further, Y/N
`=MID("NY",FIND(A5,"YN"),1)`
shows the correct "#VALUE!" for anything but Y or N

And a variant on it for full YES/NO, NOT case sensitive.
`=TRIM(MID("YESNO",FIND(UPPER(A6),"NO YES"),3))`
*Note the result of No+Space when replacing YES, unless you have TRIM().*

... and finally, to change "#VALUE!" or any other error into something more meaningful...
`=IFERROR(...;"That's a fail!")`
will display the shown text instead.
Replace "..." with any formula that may fail.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a macro in the sheet so that when you double click the cell it multiplies the value by -1 eg:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
On Error GoTo MyEndSub
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D2:D10")) Is Nothing Then Target = Target * -1
MyEndSub:
End Sub
```

Just change the range D2:D10 in the above to cover the range of interest, if you have multiple ranges just repeat the line for the ranges of interest. Press ALT + F11 to open the developer window then insert the code in the code for the sheet (double click on the sheet name in the project window open the code window for the sheet).

Then when you double click on the cell it multiplies by -1, you can select to do it by right-click instead if that if preferable.

Justin